# How to get rounded borders in drop-down button of weglot plugin in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using [Weglot plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/weglot/) in my WordPress site. I want to get the language button as a rounded border drop-down menu. The problem is, when I use `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden`, I can't see my select items and when I remove `overflow`, I get the 90° border of the the select as a background.

**Weglot button html code**

[image: weglot button html code]

**My code result**

[image: My code result]

[Weglot documentation link](https://support.weglot.com/article/81-wordpress-design-how-customize-weglot-button), if needed

**My code**

```
.country-selector{
    border-radius:36px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#cccccc;
    border:4px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of things, you're styling the container of the dropdown. Have you tried targeting the class `.wgcurrent`? That appears to be the language you have currently selected

Comment: no, if you can guide me a little more ! i'm new in css coding !

Comment: Okay! That css snippet above, you're targeting `.country-selector`. If you take your `border-radius` and `overflow-hidden` and make a new section where you're targeting the current language:

    `.wgcurrent {
        border-radius: 36px;
        overflow: hidden
    }`

There's three parts to the code snippet of the dropdown, there's the wrapper (country-selector), the currently active language (wgcurrent) and the available options. The available options are shown and hidden when the user clicks on the dropdown. I believe targeting .wgcurrent will work

Comment: thanks i can see the available options now but the border in background still rectangular [link] (https://i.imgur.com/2IMFF4l.png)

Comment: i applied border-radius on the .country-selector and it works well now thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Here is my proposition:

```
.country-selector {
    background-color: transparent!important;
} 

.country-selector .wgcurrent {
    border: 2px solid #cccccc;
         border-radius: 10px;
} 

.country-selector ul {
    background-color: white!important;
         border: 2px solid #cccccc;
         border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And you will get this:

Drop-down menu closed:

[image: Menu déroulant fermé / Drop-down menu closed]

Open drop-down menu:

[image: Menu déroulant ouvert / Open drop-down menu]